# Knockout js applybinding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

pretty new to knockout here.

I get JSON data from a web-service that gets all the dealers. I want to bind this to the GUI and later be able to filter the array based on selected region without having to get new data from the web-service and apply . Now it seems that I need both the functionality for filtering  and ko.applyBinding inside the jquery.getJSON function (in a separete function, not in page.ready as in the example). I don't want it like this, because it means that I have to get new data from the web-service and run applybinding every time the user wants to filter the array.

This code is very simplified, but I hope you get the point:

```
function GridModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Dealers = ko.observableArray();
}

var Grid_Model;    

$(document).ready(function () {  
    Grid_Model = new GridModel();  
    ko.applyBindings(Grid_Model); // If this line is here, no data is bound to the GUI at all
    jQuery.getJSON("URL", function (data) {
        Grid_Model.Dealers = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        // If I put the filter functionality here, it works
        // If I put ko.applyBindings(Grid_Model); here, it works.
    });
});

function filterDealers(string region) {
    Grid_Model.Dealers = ko.utils.arrayFilter(Grid_Model.Dealers(), function(dealer) {                
        return dealer.RegionName() == region;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to call apply bindings every time. Change your code to something like below.

```
jQuery.getJSON("URL", function (data) {
    var dealerArray = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    // Filter the dealer array here
    Grid_Model.Dealers(filteredArray);
});
```